# How to add lowercase normalizer to Elasticsearch mapping object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to add a normalizer with a lowercase option to my mapping object as it is wrote in the official Elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html)

Here is my mapping object:

```
const schema = {
    date: {
        type: 'date'
    },
    user: {
        type: 'keyword'
    },
    environment: {
        type: 'text'
    }
};

const mappingBodySchema = {
    settings: {
        analysis: {
            normalizer: {
                logsNormalizer: {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
                    filter: ['lowercase']
                }
            }
        }
    },
    mappings: {
        properties: schema
    }
};
```

And the function from elastic-js-client that I'm using to set up logs:

```
await esclient.indices.putMapping({
      index,
      body: mappingBodySchema
    });
```

But I'm receiving the following error: `ResponseError: mapper_parsing_exception`.

Can somebody advise me how can I add normalizer to the mapping object properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out how to add mapping via the elasticsearch-js-client:

```
/*
 * Closing index to change its settings
 * (A closed index is blocked for read/write operations and does not allow all operations that opened indices allow.)
 */
await esclient.indices.close({
    index
});

await esclient.indices.putSettings({
    index,
    body: mapSettings
});

// Opening index after settings update - allows to perform read/write operations
await esclient.indices.open({
    index
});

// Specifying the mapping object of our log
await esclient.indices.putMapping({
    index,
    body: {
        properties: schema
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using Type script

```
import { ElasticIndexs } from '@mylib/common';
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch';
export class Tag {
  private schema = {
    id: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    name: {
      type: 'keyword',
      normalizer: 'useLowercase',
    },
    phtoto: {
      type: 'text',
    },
  };
  constructor(private client: Client) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Tag.prototype);
  }
  async create() {
    const settings = {
      settings: {
        analysis: {
          normalizer: {
            useLowercase: {
              filter: ['lowercase'],
            },
          },
        },
      },
      mappings: {
        properties: this.schema,
      },
    };
    const { body } = await this.client.indices.exists({
      index: ElasticIndexs.Tags,
    });

    Promise.all([
      (async (client) => {
        await new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
          if (!body) {
            await client.indices.create({ index: ElasticIndexs.Tags });
          }
          resolve({ body });
        });
      })(this.client),
    ]);

    await this.client.indices.close({ index: ElasticIndexs.Tags });

    await this.client.indices.putSettings({
      index: ElasticIndexs.Tags,
      body: settings,
    });

    await this.client.indices.open({
      index: ElasticIndexs.Tags,
    });

    await this.client.indices.putMapping({
      index: ElasticIndexs.Tags,
      body: {
        properties: this.schema,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

```
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch';

class ElasticWrapper {
  private _client: Client = new Client({
    node: process.env.elasticsearch_node,
    auth: {
      username: 'elastic',
      password: process.env.elasticsearch_password || 'changeme',
    },
    ssl: {
      ca: process.env.elasticsearch_certificate,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });
  get client() {
    return this._client;
  }

}

export const elasticWrapper = new ElasticWrapper();
```

```
new Tag(elasticWrapper.client).create();
```